# Will this cause undefined behavior in Java?

Tags: java, scope

I'm working on a Java project and we have to implement a Caesar Cipher. I have all the code working, but I'm using this trick and I want to make sure that it's not going to result in undefined behavior. My understanding of Java's scope is that if I declare the `byte key` inside the function, then all references to it without using the keyword **this** will reference the local variable and using the keyword will reference the class field. I've tested the program and it works fine, but my experience with weird tricks is that they can cause undefined behavior and not work all the time.

```
Class Cipher {
    byte key = -1;

...

String encrypt(String plaintext) {
    byte key = this.key;
    if(this.key == -1) {
          System.out.print("Please enter a key: ");
          key = input.nextByte();
    }
    ...
    }
}
```

**Update:** I forgot to give some context. When you construct the class, you have the option to specify a key or not specify a key, and when you don't specify a key it will prompt for one every time you call encrypt() or decrypt(). The variable key is then used inside the function to perform the ROT shift.

Comment: I don't understand, what kind of undefined behaviour are you talking about? How it doesn't work, and what made you think that?

Comment: It will work as you were thinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is *shadowing* the `key` instance variable with a local variable `key`.  This is not undefined behavior in Java.  The [JLS, Section 6.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) has this to say:

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be used to refer to the declared entity.

and

> A declaration d of a type named n shadows the declarations of any other types named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs throughout the scope of d.

Also

> A declaration d of a local variable or exception parameter named n shadows, throughout the scope of d, (a) the declarations of any other fields named n that are in scope at the point where d occurs,

Your code will still work, because you know how to access the instance variable, by not using a simple name:

```
this.key
```

But it's bad practice to shadow variables like this.  Name the local variable something else.

Comment: So are you saying I should use a different variable entirely inside the function to perform the encryption/decryption? I can see how that makes sense, it's cleaner than shadowing the variable.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing to name a local variable the same name as another variable in scope, such as an instance variable.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that. And I just realized that if I'm using another variable anyway, I might as well name it something different.

Answer (score 1):

This will not cause undefined behavior.

After the declaration of the local variable, `this.key` will mean the class field, and `key` will mean the local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a variable named `key` in the class AND the method, Java will default to using the one with the least scope -- the one in the method.  In order to reference the one in the class, you must use the `this` keyword.

I can't double check your code because I can't see all of your uses of `key`.